# Allen Heath QU-16 mixer to Macbook Pro connect

Tags: macbook-pro

We need to hook up a macbook pro to record our sermons through GarageBand to an Allen Heath QU-16.  The macbook pro only has one headphone jack.

Answer (score 1):

Use the USB B from the mixer to you Mac, and select the Qu as the input device in yoursound preference panel. Simple, and great quality. Use 48k sample rate.

Comment: We tried this, but Garage Band did not recognize the mixer board and said only the built-in microphone could be used.

Answer (score 0):

The single headphone jack is a 3-pole connection, allowing for you to use, for example, a headset with a microphone to allow both audio in and out of the connector.  Obviously, this is in MONO for incoming, which may not be suitable for all recordings, but might well be fine for sermons.  You'll need to get a hold of a suitable adapter/splitter ([This is one example](http://www.laptopsdirect.co.uk/StarTech.com_3.5mm_4_Position_to_2x_3_Position_3.5mm_Headset_Splitter_Adapt_MUYHSMFF/version.asp?refsource=LDadwords&crtag=LD&gclid=CPyChLDl-cYCFSTItAod39APzQ), I just googled for `headset microphone splitter` , and then plug your microphone into the appropriate bit.  Alternatively, you could just pick up a USB microphone.